# Python Pandas process and merge non-matching time series as a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have the following two csv files:

- file1:

[image]

- file2:

[image]

and I want to load them in python and merge them into a single dataframe which looks like this:

[image]

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Using [pd.merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) should work:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', header=0)
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv', header=0)

result = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Date', how='outer')
```

Please check out this interesting post on how merging works: 
[Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Pandas docs on merging: 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Answer (score 1):

You don not really explain what your issue is with what you are trying to do but I suspect that you encounter problems joining on dates. Here is a solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np



Stock1 = [11.2,22.2,33.2,442,55.2,66,77,38.4]
Stock2 = [33.2,442,55.2,66,77,38.4]
begin_date1 = '2019-10-16'
begin_date2 = '2019-10-18'

df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':pd.date_range(begin_date1, periods=len(Stock1)),
                   'Stock1':Stock1 })
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'dates':pd.date_range(begin_date2, periods=len(Stock2)),
                   'Stock2':Stock2 })

DF=pd.merge(df,df2, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

[image]

I have created my own dataframes but it works just as well with yours.